# What is the difference between "instantiated" and "initialized"?

Tags: vb.net, variables

I've been hearing these two words used in Microsoft tutorials for VB.NET. What is the difference between these two words when used in reference to variables?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

#### Value vis-a-vis Reference Types

*Variables* in C# are in 1 of 2 groups. *Value* types or *Reference* types. Types like `int` and `DateTime` are *value* types. In contrast, any class you create is a *reference* type. C# strings are also a *reference* type. Most things in the .NET framework are *reference* types.

#### Parts of a Variable

There is the variable *name* and its *value*. **Two parts**.

The variable's *name* is what you ***declare*** it to be. The *value* is what you ***assign*** to it.

#### Variables are Initialized

All variables are always given an *initial* value at the point the variable is *declared*. Thus all variables are ***initialized***.

For *value* types, like `int` the compiler will give them a valid value if you do not do so explicitly. `int`'s ***initialize*** to zero by default, `DateTime`'s ***initialize*** to `DateTime.MinValue` by default.

*Reference* type variables ***initialize*** to the object you give it. The compiler will not ***assign*** an object (i.e. a valid value) if you don't. In this case the value is `null` - nothing. So we say that the reference is ***initialized*** to null.

#### Objects are Instantiated

Humans are born. Objects are instantiated. A baby is an *instance* of a Human, an object is an *instance* of some Class.

The act of creating an *instance* of a Class is called ***instantiation*** (Ta-Da!)

#### So *declare*, *initialize*, and *instantiate* come together like this

```
MyClass myClassyReference = new MyClass();
```

In the above, it is wrong to say "... creating an instance of an *object*..."

---

*edit - inspired by comments discussion*

Three distinct things are going on (above) using distinct terminology and that terminology is not interchangeable :

1. A reference variable is declared - `MyClass myClassyReference`
2. An object is instantiated (...from/of a given *class*, implied) - `new MyClass()`
3. The object is assigned to the variable. `=`.

Restating the facts:

1. A reference-type variable is also called simply "a reference". A "value-type variable" is not a reference.
2. This: "objectA is an instance of an object" is profoundly wrong. If objectA was "an instance of objectB" then it must be that objectA begins life with objectB's type - whatever that is - and current state - whatever that is. What about creating objects D, E, and F as objectB changes? Nay, nay! It is the conceptual and technical case the "objectA is an instance of a Class". "Instantiation" and "instance of" have precise meaning - an object gets its type, definitions, and values from a Class.
3. `MyClass myClassyReference = null`  Generally we don't say "the variable is assigned to null" and we never say "the variable is referencing null", No. instead we say "the variable is null"; or  "the variable is not referencing anything", or "the reference is null"

Practical Application:

- I jab my finger at your code and say "this instance has an invalid property. Maybe that's why the loop fails. You gotta validate parameters during instantiation." (i.e. constructor arguments).
- I see this in your code ,

  ```
   MyClass myClassyReference;
   myClassyReference.DoSomething();
  ```

  "You declared the variable but never assigned it. it's null so it's not referencing anything. That's why the method call throws an exception."

*end edit*

---

#### The Unbearable Lightness of Being

A *reference type* variable's name and value exists independently. And I do mean independent.

An *instantiated* object may or may not have a reference to it.

An *instantiated* object may have many references to it.

A *declared* reference may or may not be *pointing to* an object.

Comment: Perfect explanation!

Comment: If it is wrong to say: "... creating an instance of an object...", what should you say?   "...instantiating an object, and assigning a reference to it..."?

Comment: Or what about: "...instantiating an object, and initializing a variable to a reference of it"?  That includes both words and seems to spell it all out - albeit, in a rather lengthy way.  What do you think?

Comment: [... what should you say?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330767/what-is-the-difference-between-instantiated-and-initialized/11423017#comment73121427_11423017)  Say:  "creating an instance of a class", not '...of an object'.  And "instantiating a variable to a reference of it" is double talk and is wrong in 2 ways: (1) only Objects are instantiated.  (2) A variable 'pointing to' an object is a reference variable, or in short, the variable is the reference.  I'll say it differently: A "reference type" variable is a reference. It refers to - or points to - an object.

Answer (score 46):

A *variable* is initialized with a value.  An *object* is instantiated when memory is allocated for it and it's constructor has been run.

For instance here is a variable:

```
Dim obj as Object
```

This variable has not been *initialized*.  Once I assign a value to the `obj` variable, the variable will be initialized.  Here are examples of initialization:

```
obj = 1
obj = "foo"
```

Instantiation is a very different thing but is related since instantiation is usually followed by initialization:

```
Dim obj As New Object()
```

In the preceding line of code, the `obj` variable is *initialized* with the reference to the new `Object` that was *instantiated*.  We say that the new `Object` was instantiated because we have created a new instance of it.

Now I believe that VB.NET makes this a lot more confusing than C# because it is not clear that an assignment is taking place in the code above.  In C# it is much clearer that there is both an instantiation of an instance and an initialization of a variable:

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

Comment: @Andrew object obj = 1; is initialization and object obj = new object()/ is instantiation and initialization this is what you have mentioned. Now I want to ask you two things. 1. what is this? object obj; ? 2. has the memory been allocated when i use object obj;?? or it is alocated when i initialize it by this code object obj = 1; ?

Comment: I would say "object obj" is the declaration, and no, memory has not been allocated yet.  Or at least only enough memory to hold a value of "null".  The actual memory for the variable will be allocated based on the value once it is initialized.

Answer (score 21):

To *initialize* something is to set it to its initial value.  To *instantiate* something is to create an instance of it.

Often this is the more or less same thing.  This:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
```

*instantiates* a `SqlConnection` object, and *initializes* the `conn` variable by setting it to the that instance.

Since an object's constructor also sets the object's properties to their default values, it's often correct to say that instantiating an object initializes it.  (Misleading, if the object exposes a method that you have to explictly call to initialize it after it's instantiated, as is sometimes the case.)

Answer (score 4):

*Instantiation means to create an instance for a  class or object.Initialization means to *initiate the same object or class for any purpose.**

Answer (score 3):

Instantiated means that an instance of the object has been created.  Initiated means that that same object has done some initialization.

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate a class or object, you're creating a new instance of it, or allocating memory to "hold" one. Initializing that object would be the instructions that are performed during instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

Instantiation is when you create an instance of a class.  That instance is then an object, and you can set its properties, or call methods on it (tell it to do things).

Initiation is when you set up a set of initial conditions for something.  That something might be an object, where you tell it to initiate itself, or just a variable to which you assign a value.

An object might initialise some other things, or even instantiate other objects as part of its initiation.

The difference is that instantiation is creation of a thing that can do stuff; initiation is stuff that gets done.

Answer (score 1):

See the Java docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

"**Point originOne** = new Point(23, 94);

```
Declaration: The code set in bold are all variable declarations that associate a variable name with an object type.
Instantiation: The new keyword is a Java operator that creates the object.
Initialization: The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, which initializes the new object."
```

Answer (score 1):

We can see it this way. For a line of code below:

```
var p = new Person();
```

The above line can be read as following two ways:

1. The variable p has been **initialized** as a person class
2. Person class has been **instantiated** in variable p

The subject of reference or context matters. When talking in terms of *variable*, we use the word ***initialize***. When talking in terms of *class/type*, we use the word ***instantiate***.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiation refers to the allocation of memory to create an instance of a class whereas initialization refers to naming that instance by assigning the variable name to that instance.

Eg: `SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();`

Here `new` is a keyword which allocates memory for an instance and `conn` is a variable name assigned for that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained the difference, so I wont go into detail. But there are cases where instantiation does not properly initialize an object. When you instantiate an object you also initialize it with some data. The class/type will have the initialization logic, whereas the instantiation logic is typically carried out by the`new` keyword (basically memory allocation, reference copying etc). But instantiation need not necessarily result in a valid state for objects which is when we can say the object is *uninitialzed*. Here's a practical example where an object can be instantiated but not initialized (sorry e.g. in C#).

```
class P { string name = "Ralf"; }

WriteLine(new P().name); // "Ralf";
WriteLine((FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(P)) as P).name); // null
```

`GetUninitializedObject` doesn't call the constructor to instantiate object there (but some internal magic).

One could also argue value types are not instantiated but only initialized as it doesn't need new allocation when you do `new..` but that's up to one's definition of instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

In object-oriented parlance:

- To **instantiate** means creating an object of some class, which initial state may be undefined.

  The class is a blueprint which is used by the program to create objects. Objects created are compliant with the blueprint and can be manipulated by the program. E.g. variables `current_client` and `previous_client` can be assigned objects of class `Customer`. An *instance of class X* is an object instantiated from class X.

  In the code the class is a permanent static description of what an object can do, but the objects themselves are temporary and dynamic. They have an individual state which can be changed (e.g. the Customer name, the associated orders). Instantiation can be done like this:

  `dim current_client as new Customer` (VB)
  `Customer* current_client = new Customer()` (C++)
  `current_client = Customer()` (Python)

  `new Customer`, `new Customer()` and `Customer()` are equivalent forms in different languages to trigger the instantiation.

  In the end objects are destructed to release memory and other resources required for their existence and working.
- To **initialize** means assigning an initial state to the object before it is used.

  This initialization can be part of the instantiation process, in that case values are explicitly assigned to object attributes in the constructor of the object. Alternatively it can be left to the user who can decide whether it is required or not. The latter method allows faster instantiation, but requires the user's code to not read the value of any attribute before this code has explicitly assigned a value to this attribute. E.g. this code:

  `current_client.count = current_client.count + 1`

  is not allowed before the attribute `count` has been set by the user, since it can contain any initial value, including an invalid value which would trigger an execution error.