# How to change object value from another class in Java (look like same as Arraylist)?

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I'm confused about `ArrayList` with another variable that can change the value from another class.
I have two classes and two examples with the `ArrayList` and `Object` variables.
Can somebody help me to understand why it's different and if there is a solution to make it have the same effect?

This is the code with ArrayList:

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    private String name = "Fifi";
    
    void fill(List<Test> a) {
        a.add(this);
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class B {
    private List<Test> a = new ArrayList<Test>();
    //a variable is empty

    public B() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Test oa = new Test();
        oa.fill(a);// After this method is called, a variable has change with name is "FiFi"
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
    }
}
```

And then, I have the same form like that with the object variable, but the result is not the same.

```java
public class Test {
    private String name = "Fifi";
    
    void fill(Test b) {
        b = this;
    }
}
```

```java
public class B {
    private Test a;
    // so a variable is null

    public B() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Test oa = new Test();
        oa.fill(a);// after fill method is called, a still null!
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
    }
}
```

What is different from Arraylist and object variables like above? I do not understand the basics of how it's happening!

Comment: In your first example, you never use the private List<Test> that you've created, only a new local list that you throw away when your method exits.

Comment: @NomadMaker it is used to add instance of Test class into it, check more carefully

Comment: @eis Yes, you are right. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

`ArrayList` and `Object` are two completely different concepts. [Arraylist](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp)   [Object](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_class_attributes.asp)

> oa.fill(a); // after fill method is called, a still null!

`a` is null because this

> private Test a;

is not an object but a reference of `Test` class. So no memory is allocated to `a`. [Difference between declaration and instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484122/14680048)

```
private Test a = new Test(); //object is created
```

Difference between your two codes:

This code is appending an object(`oa`) of `Test` class to List `a`-

```
public class Test {
    private String name = "Fifi";
    
    void fill(List<Test> a) {
        a.add(this);
    }
}
```

And in this code you are assigning contents of one object(`oa`) to another object(`a`) of same class `Test`-

```
    public B() {
        Test oa = new Test();
        oa.fill(a);
        System.out.print(a.name); //output: Fifi
    }
```

Comment: it wouldn't change anything even if `private Test a;` would be an object, such as `private Test a = new Test();`. The code OP tries still wouldn't work, because assigning to reference passed as value won't work. you would need to use reference as reference.

Comment: @eis  Did you run the code? Can you clarify your point after running this code because what you said in the first line isn't consistent with the output. If what you're saying is true then how is the value of `a.name` changing to 'Fifi' after `oa.fill(a)`

Comment: it's not changing, with or without new object creation. it will only change if List<Test> is being used, not when Test is used. This is due to the reference usage I explained.

Comment: @eis it is changing with new object creation that's why I asked you to execute the code.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the problem. here's a runnable demonstration for you showing that it does not change: https://ideone.com/1LNzAw

Comment: @eis I never said that reference will change. Obviously the reference will not change because they are two different objects. OP is asking about value(attributes) change not reference change. I said everything with respect to values. See this- https://ideone.com/zjLBdd

Comment: there's no point discussing since you don't seem to understand the problem. in your example fill() method still does nothing outside the fill method, and object instantiation is irrelevant to the issue.