# ArrayList data sharing between java class

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

I've fetched data from Firebase to the Dashboard (Fragment) Main class , and now I need to access that same ArrayList to another Fragment class. How do i share arraylists between two classes.

**My Code from the Dashboard Class:**

```
private void GetCategory() {


    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category");
    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Catergory_List cl = userSnapshot.getValue(Catergory_List.class);
                CatList.add(cl);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

**My Second Class**

```
private Dashboard db;
            TExpenses= db.TrasactionExpenses();
        System.out.println(TExpenses.size());
```

**And i tried this code and its not working**

```
  public List<Catergory_List> TrasactionExpenses() {
        return CatList;
    }
```

**Error Log**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List Dashboard.TrasactionExpenses()' on a null object reference
```

Any help would be appreciated..i'm unable to get the Values from Dashboard Class ArrayList to Class B

Comment: Where did you define `CatList`?

Comment: Where are you setting your `Dashboard` instance in your second class? All your code shows is you declaring the `db` variable without assigning it a value and then getting a null-pointer exception for calling a method on it.

Comment: private List<Catergory_List> CatList; is under Dashboard class and Under onCreate viewCatList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Yes, but it is the `Dashboard` variable  that is `null`, not `CatList`.

Comment: Under Dashboard CatList am able to get the data but when i go the class b its not working and I tried do under onCreateView Dashboard db=new Dashboard(); still not

Comment: You should use Java standards for your code, particularly in naming types, variables, and methods.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, you did not initialize your Dashboard !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the constructor for Dashboard looks like, but you'll need to initialize the Dashboard object. You've only declared declared the dashboard `db`. (See the first answer for initialization vs. instantiation vs. declaration [Difference between initializing a class and instantiating an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074083/difference-between-initializing-a-class-and-instantiating-an-object))

You'll need to do something like:

```
Dashboard db = new Dashboard();
```

in your second class.