# Initialisation or instantiation

Tags: c++, oop, object

Which best describes the following:

<del>A a();</del>

```
A a;
```

Where "A" is a generic class? I've always believed you were initialising an object for the class, but, others seem to think of instantiation - Something I've only really come across in VB.net.

Thoughts please? :)

Comment: Neither. It is a function declaration.

Comment: My C++ is pretty rusty, but I believe it's declaring and initializing a automatic variable "a" of type "A".

Comment: You initialize a variable, but objects are instantiated. 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330767/what-is-the-difference-between-instantiated-and-initialized][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330767/what-is-the-difference-between-instantiated-and-initialized

Comment: There's no such thing as a "generic class" in C++. Classes in C++ are types, and types are always specific.

Comment: @HotLicks no, it is declaring a parameter-less function `a` that returns an `A`. C++ is a bit strange sometimes.

Comment: (For `A a;` which was intended)  This is highly dependent on location and some other context.  I could also see the words "declaration" and "definition" entering contention.

Comment: @juanchopanza - OK, then it's the other way -- `A a(x);` is declaring and initializing the automatic variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
A a();
```

It declares a function which returns `A` type. This is a surprise to many users.  This is related to the [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

In the following two examples, the intent is obvious

```
A a(3);    // an object a, of type A, initialized with 3
A a(int);  // a *function* a, taking an int parameter and returning A
```

But when the brackets are empty, the default is a function declaration.  If you want a variable, you should remove the `()`;

```
A a;
```

Comment: no, it can define variable a of type A with default constructor called

Comment: @IlyaBursov you should try to call `a` member in your code to find out.

Comment: I've expanded the answer, I hope you don't mind @billz.  Feel free to undo what I've done.

Comment: my fault, forgot about A a; syntax

Answer (score 0):

This is a Declaration for most of the cases. This declares a function named `a` which returns type `A` and takes no arguments.

Since A could be a macro or something weird, I would not say it is always a declaration.

Comment: What does "for most of the cases if A is type" mean?! What *else* could `A` possibly be?

Comment: Sneaky, but true :-) Though if any token in the question could be a macro, then it's hard to say *anything*. The code could be a bittorrent client, for all we know.

Comment: In fact, I'd go as far as assuming that for a general C++ question on SO, none of the tokens that aren't explicitly shown to be macros are in fact macros, since that would really just make *every* question completely unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your complete program is:

```
class A
{
};

A a;
```

Then the answer is "both".

C++ has terminology that is not necessarily the same as that of other languages. Using the C++ terminology, the *declaration* `A a` declares an *object* `a` of *type* `A`.

This *declaration* is also a *definition*. The type `A` is required to be *complete*.

[Note: If the type `A` was a *template specialization* (e.g. `typedef X<int> A`), that specialization would be *implicitly instantiated*.]

In the C++ terminology, *initialization* means to give an initial *value* for an object. In the example, the object `a` will be *default-initialized*, which may result in no actual initialization being performed.

The dictionary [definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/instantiate) of the term "instantiation" is an appropriate way to describe this declaration. The declaration "instantiates" an object `a`, which is an "instance" of the class `A`.