# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040013): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040013

Tags: c#, asp.net, r

I want to find a entropy for an image using R programming with the help of Asp.Net.I have downloaded and install the statconnDCOM to there default location.i'm using following assembly

using STATCONNECTORCLNTLib;

using StatConnectorCommonLib;

using STATCONNECTORSRVLib;

My C# code is

```
    static StatConnector rconn;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            //Calculate Statistics in R
            rconn.Init("R");
            rconn.Evaluate("require(indicoio)");
            rconn.Evaluate("require(jpeg)");
            rconn.Evaluate("imgPath<-C:/Users/Sunil/Desktop/apple2.jpg");

            //Read the image into a raster array
            rconn.Evaluate("img<-readJPEG(imgPath, native = FALSE)");

            //convert the array to a data.frame or matrix
            rconn.Evaluate("mystring<-as.data.frame(img)");
            rconn.Evaluate("myfreqs <- mystring / sum(mystring)");

            //vectorize
            rconn.Evaluate("myvec <- as.data.frame(myfreqs)[,2]");

            // H in bit
            double average = (double)rconn.GetSymbol(rconn.Evaluate("-sum(myvec * log2(myvec))"));

            Console.WriteLine("Entropy is: " + average);
            Console.ReadLine();           


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: I used static StatConnector rconn=new StatConnector(); to solve the problem but now I'm getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040013): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040013
   at StatConnectorCommonLib.IStatConnector.Init(String bstrConnectorName) error

Answer (score 1):

Your `rconn` object is not instantiated. At the beggining of `Main` function add:

```
rconn = new StatConnector();
```

Comment: after initialization of rconn  I'm getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040013): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040013 at StatConnectorCommonLib.IStatConnector.Init(String bstrConnectorName) error

Comment: @Daniel Nitpicking: You're actually wrong. `rconn` *is* initialized. It's initialized to `null`. However, it's not instantiated ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330767/what-is-the-difference-between-instantiated-and-initialized

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå - LOL, that's true ;)

Comment: do you have any solution for System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040013)

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377070/c-sharp-r-interface

Comment: it's not working in my case. Any other solution???