# Meanings of declaring, instantiating, initializing and assigning an object

Tags: c#, terminology

Technically what are the meanings and differences of the terms *declaring*, *instantiating*, *initializing* and *assigning* an object in C#?

I think I know the meaning of assigning but I have no formal definition.

In msdn, it is said "the act of creating an object is called instantiation". But the meaning *creating* seems vague to me. You can write

```
int a;
```

is `a` then created?

Comment: i have never seen `clarifying`. but `instantiating` means to create an instance of an object. `initializing` means setting value to an object.(does not necessarily create new instance). `assigning` is self descriptive. assign a value to an object. i maybe wrong. but thats what i think

Comment: FYI, int is a primitive type, not an object.

Comment: sorry I meant declaring.

Comment: declaring is just what you have shown. like `int a;` you declared an `int` named `a` but you still not initialized it.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary after this declaration, does `a=2` initialize it? instantiate it?

Comment: instantiate is for class objects. means create a new object with new reference. for a=2 you say initialize.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Do you mean `a` is not an object because `int` is not a class?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330767/what-is-the-difference-between-instantiated-and-initialized

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Declaring** - Declaring a variable means to introduce a new variable to the program. You define its type and its name.

```
int a; //a is declared
```

**Instantiate** - Instantiating a class means to create a new instance of the class. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx#InstantiatingClasses).

```
MyObject x = new MyObject(); //we are making a new instance of the class MyObject
```

**Initialize** - To initialize a variable means to assign it an initial value.

```
int a; //a is declared
int a = 0; //a is declared AND initialized to 0
MyObject x = new MyObject(); //x is declared and initialized with an instance of MyObject
```

**Assigning** - Assigning to a variable means to provide the variable with a value.

```
int a = 0; //we are assigning to a; yes, initializing a variable means you assign it a value, so they do overlap!
a = 1; //we are assigning to a
```

Comment: So Instantiation is not used for structs or simple types?

Comment: Can "initializing" mean "assigning for the first time after declaration"?

Comment: The term is used for structs, although I am honestly not sure why. However "instantiate" is not used for simple types. And yes, that is basically the meaning of initialize. @MinimusHeximus

Answer (score 13):

In general:

***Declare*** means to tell the compiler that something exists, so that space may be allocated for it. This is separate from defining or initializing something in that it does not necessarily say what "value" the thing has, only that it exists. In C/C++ there is a strong distinction between declaring and defining. In C# there is much less of a distinction, though the terms can still be used similarly.

***Instantiate*** literally means "to create an instance of". In programming, this generally means to create an instance of an object (generally on "the heap"). This is done via the `new` keyword in most languages. ie: `new object();`. Most of the time you will also save a reference to the object. ie: `object myObject = new object();`.

***Initialize*** means to give an initial value to. In some languages, if you don't initialize a variable it will have arbitrary (dirty/garbage) data in it. In C# it is actually a compile-time error to read from an uninitialized variable.

***Assigning*** is simply the storing of one value to a variable. `x = 5` assigns the value `5` to the variable `x`. In some languages, assignment cannot be combined with declaration, but in C# it can be: `int x = 5;`.

Note that the statement `object myObject = new object();` combines all four of these.

- `new object()` instantiates a new `object` object, returning a reference to it.
- `object myObject` declares a new `object` reference.
- `=` initializes the reference variable by assigning the value of the reference to it.

Comment: Do we have the term *defining* too? What *defining* means?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Define means give a value (or body) to. We don't really use "define" much in C#, but it would be similar in meaning to initialize. When you write a method, I guess you could call that defining the method, though it doesn't have any contrast with declaring the method like it would in C++.