# "Use of unassigned local variable" error even though I assign the variable?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

In the example below, the compiler generates an error "Use of unassigned local variable `r`", even though I assign the variable in loop before using it. Why does the compiler generate this error?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float r;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        r = i; // assigned here

    Console.WriteLine(r); // error: use of unassigned local variable            
}
```

Comment: I guess you need this `float r = 0;`

Comment: The compiler isn't going to inspect the `for` loop, because of the halting problem. A `for` introduces a condition, so the variable is not considered unconditionally assigned.

Answer (score 11):

The compiler generates that error whenever it detects an unassigned variable is *possible*.

Because the body of `for` loops are not guaranteed to execute—for example, `for(int i = 123; i < 0; i++)`—the variable is not guaranteed to be assigned, and so the compiler generates the error.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d.aspx):

> The C# compiler does not allow the use of uninitialized variables. If the compiler detects the use of a variable that might not have been initialized, it generates compiler error CS0165. For more information, see [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx). Note that this error is generated when the compiler encounters a construct that might result in the use of an unassigned variable, even if your particular code does not. This avoids the necessity of overly-complex rules for definite assignment.

Comment: I understand your answer from other Types but float has a default value (0).
same happens with int, which also has a default value of 0 according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values

Comment: Default values come into play when you initialize a variable; they aren’t involved in a declaration. This answer has a helpful breakdown of the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32291033/3159635

Comment: what I don't understand is, how the default value plays a role, when it only comes into play when I initialize a variable. Lets say, I `int i = 1;` it could never be the default value, except I go for `int i = 0;` what are the default values for then?