# Using variable outside of the for loop

Tags: c#, excel, loops

I have a problem with:

```
public void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CellDataID;
    string[] IDString;
    for (int RowCount = 2; RowCount <= LastRow; RowCount++)
    {
        xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlSht.Cells[RowCount, colNumberID];
        CellDataID = (string)xlRange.Text;
        PrinterBox1.Items.Add(CellDataID);
        IDString = new string[LastRow];
        IDString[RowCount - 1] = CellDataID;  
    }
}
```

I need to use all of `IDString[]` items outside of the loop, but have no idea how to do it. VS C# is saying that the variable must have any value/declaration if i want to use it. Can anyone help me?

I had couple of nightmares about loops this week..

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this code. I was going to answer that you should declare the variable before the loop but you've done that...

Comment: VS C# is saying that the variable must have any value/declaration if i want to use it and declaration is set in the loop and i do not know how to pull it out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never [instanciate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290879/meanings-of-declaring-instantiating-initializing-and-assigning-an-object) `IDString` or give it a length.

```
string[] IDString;
```

You likely need something like this:

```
string CellDataID;
//List<T>(s) are more flexible than arrays
//new instantiates it
List<string> IDString = new List<string>;
for (int RowCount = 2; RowCount <= LastRow; RowCount++)
{
    xlRange = (Excel.Range)xlSht.Cells[RowCount, colNumberID];
    CellDataID = (string)xlRange.Text;
    PrinterBox1.Items.Add(CellDataID);
    //this is just wrong.
    //IDString = new string[LastRow];

    //add the string to your list
    IDString.Add(CellDataID);  
}
```

If you need an array just do:

```
IDString.ToArray()
```

Or better yet just pass it into your methods using [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558304/can-anyone-explain-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-to-me) this will then accept an `array` or a `List<T>`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
IDString.Any(y => y == something)
```

there you can use your Array without a foreach Loop.