unable to locate where to add } to fix } expected error?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class TopicSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextMeshProUGUI topicText;
    public string[] allTopics = new string[9];
    public string winText;
    private int topicIndex;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        topicIndex = Random.Range(0, 8);
        GameObject persistantObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PersistentObj") as GameObject;
        winText = persistantObj.GetComponent<PersistenceScript>().winText;
        public GameObject cards = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CardPosition");
    }  

}

Above is my code and from the error message, it can be inferred that a curly braces } seems to be missing somewhere. However I am having difficulty locating where to add the }. The bracket pair guides of my VSCode editor is also not showing the dashed line for the start method somehow. Does anyone know how I can fix it? Thank you.

public GameObject cards... inside a function is incorrect. Local variables do not have access specifiers.

Please read [mre]. Is any of the Update method required to reproduce the problem? No. It should not be included.

you should move the declaration of cards directly into your class and instantiate it in your Start-function.
public class TopicSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] catCards = new GameObject[9];
    public GameObject[] hamsterCards = new GameObject[9];
    public GameObject[] dogCards = new GameObject[9];
    public GameObject[] rabbitCards = new GameObject[9];
    public GameObject cards;

    public TextMeshProUGUI topicText;
    public string[] allTopics = new string[9];
    public string winText;
    private int topicIndex;
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Start()
    {
        topicIndex = Random.Range(0, 8);
        GameObject persistantObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PersistentObj") as GameObject;
        winText = persistantObj.GetComponent<PersistenceScript>().winText;
        cards = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CardPosition");
    } 
}

If the terms "declaration" and "instantiation" are unfamiliar to you, it may help to read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32291033/2528063

You seem to have inadvertently tried to declare a field, and assign it a value inside your Start() method
    void Start()
    {
        ...
        public GameObject cards = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CardPosition");
    }

This is not valid.
You should instead declare the field separately, along with the other fields so it is available later in your code.
    public GameObject[] catCards = new GameObject[9];
    public GameObject[] hamsterCards = new GameObject[9];
    public GameObject[] dogCards = new GameObject[9];
    public GameObject[] rabbitCards = new GameObject[9];
    public GameObject cards;

And then initialize it separately in Startup()
    void Start()
    {
        ...
        cards = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CardPosition")
    }


You just need to swap these two lines:
    public GameObject cards = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CardPosition");
}

The code should be:
void Start()
{
    topicIndex = Random.Range(0, 8);
    GameObject persistantObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PersistentObj") as GameObject;
    winText = persistantObj.GetComponent<PersistenceScript>().winText;
}

public GameObject cards = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CardPosition");

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    topicText.text = allTopics[topicIndex];


    winText = persistantObj.GetComponent<PersistenceScript>().winText;
    public GameObject cards = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CardPosition");

You should delete public keyword

The error is not any bracket. It is you are declaring variable cards inside Start() and calling it in Update(). Declare variable first outside as global, like you do with the others and initialize it inside Start().

Hi Pablo, You can place a comment if you're not 95% sure that you've got the right answer. Please don't provide a guess as an answer.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Okey, I'm sorry, It's just my way to talk, but I'll edit it to show more safety on my words. I mean, I'm sure the error was that.
