# Unity how to create an object without the new keyword

Tags: c#, class, object, unity-game-engine

I was wondering why is it that when I create a custom class, I have to declare an object like this:

```
 Person Bob = new Person;
```

But with Unity's custom classes I don't; Example:

```
 puiblic RaycastHit hit;
 public Color myColor;
 public RigidBody rB;
```

Comment: [Read This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330767/what-is-the-difference-between-instantiated-and-initialized/11423017#11423017)

Comment: `Person Bob = new Person` won't compile anyway.   `RigidBody` **is** a class so you **will** have to call `new` so not sure where you got that idea from

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is so simple it is unlikely to have any use for future readers

Answer (score 0):

The latter example is just creating a variable that **can** hold an instance of an object. It's not actually creating an instance of anything.

If those variables happen to be structs, they'll have a default value.

Answer (score 0):

`RaycastHit` and `Color` are not `class`es, they are `struct`s.  This means that they are declared just like an `int` would be, and they can be immediately put to use without the need for `new`.

`RigidBody`, on the other hand, is a `class`, so this declaration does not instantiate an object, it just declares a reference to an object, which will have to be instantiated or otherwise obtained further down.