# What's the correct terminology when referring to an instance?

Tags: php, instance, terminology

There's lots of questions here on objects, classes, instances, instantiation etc... But I can't find the answer to my question. I'm trying to write some documentation and having trouble finding the correct terminology to use.

There's a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330767/what-is-the-difference-between-instantiated-and-initialized) that's related, but not what I'm looking for here.

There's also some basic info over on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)).

Consider the following (in the PHP realm although it may be the same for other languages) :

Let's say I have singleton class:

```
class fooBar
{
    protected static $instance;

    private function __construct() {
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new fooBar;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

I then instantiate the class:

```
$foo = fooBar::getInstance();
```

Later on in my code I use the `getInstance` method to get a reference:

```
$bar = fooBar::getInstance();
```

So when I'm referring to `$bar`, what is the correct terminology:

1. `$bar` is a reference to the fooBar class instance.
2. `$bar` is a reference to a fooBar class instance.
3. `$bar` is the fooBar class instance.
4. `$bar` returns a reference to the fooBar class instance.
5. `$bar` returns the fooBar class instance.
6. `$bar` returns a fooBar class instance.

Which of these is correct (if any) ?

Lastly, when referring to the already instantiated `fooBar` class in general do I refer to it as "The fooBar instance"?

Answer (score 1):

It is a variable which holds fooBar class singleton instance. Since objects in PHP are passed by reference it is the same as fooBar class singleton instance. I would say go with option 3), everybody will understand you. Options 4)-6) are simply incorrect and 1) looks overcomplicated for me.